# How to substract from dictionary value in Python?

Tags: python

I must substract from dictionary values.

```
list1 = {'i': 1, 'k': 1, 'j': 1, 'o': 2, 'q': 1, 's': 1, 'x': 1, 'z': 1}
string = 'ikjoosgx'
for letter in string:
I NEED TO DECREASE list1 key of same name as letter VALUE BY 1. DIPSIT!
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on the approaches you tried during these two hours?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another solution, this time using the good old [`setdefault`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#mapping-types-dict):

```
list1 = {'i': 1, 'k': 1, 'j': 1, 'o': 2, 'q': 1, 's': 1, 'x': 1, 'z': 1}
string1 = 'ikjoosgx'
for letter in string1:
    list1[letter] = list1.setdefault(letter, 0) - 1
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for letter in my_string:
    list1[letter] -= 1
```

As a side note, don't ever use `string` as a variable name, as it is also the name of a standard module.

This won't work if one of the letters isn't in the dictionary. In that case, you can put a `try/except` block in the loop.

```
for letter in my_string:
    try:
        list1[letter] -= 1
    except KeyError:
        pass  # your error handling goes here
```

If you want a default value you can replace `pass` with:

```
list1[letter] = default_value
```

Or you could just use [Ocaso's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14579131/1907098).

Comment: But man, it won't work I already tied =( =( OK, I'll try again brb in second with answer

Comment: Beware! There is a 'g' in the string, which is not a key in list1, so you will get a KeyError

Comment: Hey, no problem! Thx, it worked. If it's not, we can always use default number. So yeah, it seems it works properly now =)

Comment: Better to put the `try/except` inside the loop, I think.

Answer (score 1):

if i get your question right you want this:

```
list1 = {'i': 1, 'k': 1, 'j': 1, 'o': 2, 'q': 1, 's': 1, 'x': 1, 'z': 1}
string = 'ikjoosgx'
for letter in string:
    if letter in list1:
        list1[letter] -= 1

print list1
>>> {'q': 1, 's': 0, 'z': 1, 'i': 0, 'x': 0, 'k': 0, 'j': 0, 'o': 0}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is simple:

```
d[key] -= 1
```

Just iterate of the keys:

```
for letter in string:
    d[letter] -= 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for letter in string:
    list1[letter] = list1[letter] - 1
```

Comment: How do you handle the letter 'g' in string? 'g' is not a key in the dict!

Comment: like the others have said, use a try catch statement